# start_time not corresponding to event's start time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm in TZ Paris (GMT +1) and I fetch some events using PHP.

First, I set the default TZ to Los Angeles : 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

Everything works fine and I get the correct date/time.

Except for one event : https://www.facebook.com/events/115566628587479/

The event shows : 17:00 – 20:00 (UTC-04)

When I fetch the event using FQL, a start_time timestamp is returned : 1343023200 which is Mon, 23 Jul 2012 06:00:00 PST -> converted to 2012-07-22 23:00:00 by the date_default_timezone_set function.

This doesn't correspond to the event's date/time.

Any idea on where I'm going wrong ?

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

> First, I set the default TZ to Los Angeles : date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

Well, that’s your error right there – because when you [look up the event with the Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=115566628587479), you’ll see hat is has a different timezone set:

> "timezone": "America/Montreal"